# virtualenv для python3

Tags: python

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential

~$ mkdir envs

~$ cd envs

~/envs$ virtualenv some_project

~/envs$ source some_project/bin/activate

(some_project)user@my_pc:~$ pip install Django
```

В виртуальной среде python 2.7/ а как поставить python3?

Answer (score 4):

Вместо virtualenv советую использовать модуль Python 3 venv:
Переходим в папку с проектом:

```
$  mkdir ~/project && cd ~/project
```

Создаём виртуальное окружение:

```
$  python3 -m venv prj
```

Активируем его:

```
$ . prj/bin/activate
```

Устанавливаем Django:

```
(prj) $ pip install Django
```

Comment: ТЭкс)) Стоп-стоп)) Дело в том что я только начинающий. Читаю вот лутца и пробую проходить djbook. Почему Вы советуете использовать venv? В чем разница?

Comment: @Sokolov.G venv это по сути тот же virualenv, только реализованный как стандартный модуль python. Появился на волне популярности virtualenv в python 3.3. Так как я далёк от особенностей реализации каждого из пакетов, предпочитаю использовать venv хотя-бы потому, что это стандартный модуль. цитата с [хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/157287/) "Он почти такой же, как virtualenv, только немного лучше."

Comment: @Sokolov.G P.S. Я сам python изучаю, по-видимому, на две недели дольше вас, только вместо django выбрал Flask :D

Comment: Ну спишемся) Спасибо!!!

Comment: E: Unable to locate package python3-venv  Не ставится venv

Comment: @Sokolov.G sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python3-venv
Если у вас не убунту (минт например), попробуйте установить python3.4-venv или python3.5-venv

Answer (score 2):

1.Установить python3 в ОС:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-dev ...
```

2.Создать виртуальную среду, указав путь к python3

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 envs
```

Comment: Учебник написан для Django 1.9 и Python 3.4 и выше. Если версия Django отличается, вы можете обратиться к документации, соответствующей версии Django, или обновить Django до последней версии. Если вы все еще используете Python 2.7, ваш код может отличаться от приведенного в этом учебнике, и вы должны немного изменить, как это будет указано в комментариях. Значит мне virtualenv для python3 поставить?

Comment: А virtualenv myproject создает проект на Python 2.7 Почему так?

Comment: @Sokolov.G По умолчанию, команда virtualenv использует путь /usr/bin/python2.7, но Флаг -p позволяет указать вручную требуемую версию python.

Answer (score 1):

В системе могут быть установлены как 2 версия, так и 3. Если я Вас правильно понял, то при создании виртуального окружения можно использовать параметр команды "`--python=python3.5`", который принудительно скажет использовать только python3.5 в будущем django проекте.

Например:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --python=python3.5 temp
```